# jQuery get object by id from div by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get an onClick event on found by id checkbox in div(should find it by id too).

My code is:

```
$('#myDivId').find('#myCheckboxId').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
            }
            else{
            }
});
```

but something goes wrong. I know that there should be one Id in page but is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What you have should work - assuming you have only one element with that `id`. If you have duplicated `id` then you need to remove them and use classes instead

Comment: Does it change anything if you replace `this` by `$(this)` ?

Comment: unfortunately I have two the same structured tables (the same ids and classes) with different content. I can only put every table in different div (can not modify tables)

Comment: What is going wrong? Is the selector not working?

Comment: Then with same id,its not gonna work if its same page, regardless of if iframe.

Comment: @PaulGerbert that's definitely an issue you should address. However if the tables already have classes on, you can use those. Please add your HTML to the question

Comment: change function does not work. replace it with click

Comment: @GaneshRadhakrishnan that's completely incorrect. `change` is the preferred event to use on a checkbox as it allows people who navigate via the keyboard to raise the event when changing the checkbox state

Comment: if you have multiple checkboxes change the id selected and give class for it.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I think what u said was correct. I didn't think about the keyboard navigation. I thought about the click event only. But here we don't know whether is there only one checkbox or not. If there is multiple checkboxes, he might not give an id. Instead of that he need to give classname. Am i right?

Comment: That would seem to be the case. The previous comments have all asked the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#myDivId>#myCheckboxId').change(function() {
 if (this.checked) {
   console.log('checked!');
 }
 else{
   console.log('not checked');
 }
});
```

Example is [here](http://jsbin.com/wijuto/1/edit).

Comment: `find()` is not equivalent to the child selector. Also, if the OPs code doesn't work this won't either.